# Change the font family in WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I wish to change the font used for displaying the text in WebView. I have tried several possible threads at StackOverflow but ended up in failure in getting the results. Following is my code that deals with the webview.

XML Code:

```
 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title_text"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_8dp" />
```

Here is my PostDetailsActivity.java file which uses this:

```
package com.mcc.wpnews.activity;
public class PostDetailsActivity extends BaseActivity implements WriteACommentFragment.OnCompleteListener {

// Variables
private Activity mActivity;
private Context mContext;

// init views
private RelativeLayout lytPostDetailsView, lytCommentDetails;
private int clickedPostId;
private ImageView imgPost;
private TextView tvPostTitle, tvPostAuthor, tvPostDate, tvCommnentList;
private WebView webView;
private FloatingActionButton fabWriteAComment;
private ImageButton imgBtnSpeaker, imgBtnFav, imgBtnShare;
private PostDetails model = null;

// Favourites view
private List<FavouriteModel> favouriteList;
private FavouriteDbController favouriteDbController;
private boolean isFavourite = false;

// Comments view
private List<CommentsAndReplies> commentList;
private List<CommentsAndReplies> zeroParentComments;
List<CommentsAndReplies> onlyThreeComments;
private int mPerPage = 5;
private RecyclerView rvComments;
private CommentsAdapter commentsAdapter = null;

// Text to speech
private TtsEngine ttsEngine;
private boolean isTtsPlaying = false;
private String ttsText;

private WebEngine webEngine;

private boolean fromPush = false, fromAppLink = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initVar();
    initView();
    initFunctionality();
    initListener();
}

private void initVar() {
    mActivity = PostDetailsActivity.this;
    mContext = mActivity.getApplicationContext();

    // Favourites view
    favouriteList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Comments view
    commentList = new ArrayList<>();
    zeroParentComments = new ArrayList<>();
    onlyThreeComments = new ArrayList<>();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {
        clickedPostId = extras.getInt(AppConstant.BUNDLE_KEY_POST_ID, 0);
        if(extras.containsKey(AppConstant.BUNDLE_FROM_PUSH)) {
            fromPush = extras.getBoolean(AppConstant.BUNDLE_FROM_PUSH);
        }
        if(extras.containsKey(AppConstant.BUNDLE_FROM_APP_LINK)) {
            fromAppLink = extras.getBoolean(AppConstant.BUNDLE_FROM_APP_LINK);
        }
    }

}

private void initView() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_details);

    lytPostDetailsView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt_post_details);
    lytCommentDetails = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt_comment_list);
    //lytParentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    imgPost = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.post_img);
    tvPostTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    tvPostAuthor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_author);
    tvPostDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_text);
    imgBtnSpeaker = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnSpeaker);
    imgBtnFav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnFavourite);
    imgBtnShare = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnShare);

    initWebEngine();


    tvCommnentList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comment_count);
    fabWriteAComment = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_new_comment);

    rvComments = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvComments);
    rvComments.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    initLoader();

    initToolbar();
    enableBackButton();

}

public void initWebEngine() {

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    webEngine = new WebEngine(webView, mActivity);
    webEngine.initWebView();


    webEngine.initListeners(new WebListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            initLoader();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded() {
            hideLoader();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(int progress) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNetworkError() {
            showEmptyView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageTitle(String title) {
        }
    });
}

private void initFunctionality() {

    favouriteDbController = new FavouriteDbController(mContext);
    favouriteList.addAll(favouriteDbController.getAllData());
    for (int i = 0; i < favouriteList.size(); i++) {
        if (favouriteList.get(i).getPostId() == clickedPostId) {
            isFavourite = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    ttsEngine = new TtsEngine(mActivity);

    commentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(mActivity, (ArrayList) commentList, (ArrayList) onlyThreeComments);
    rvComments.setAdapter(commentsAdapter);

    showLoader();
    loadPostDetails();

    // show full-screen ads
    // AdUtils.getInstance(mContext).showFullScreenAd();

}

public void setFavImage() {
    if (isFavourite) {
        imgBtnFav.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity, R.drawable.ic_book));
    } else {
        imgBtnFav.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity, R.drawable.ic_un_book));
    }
}

public void initListener() {

    imgBtnSpeaker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (model != null) {
                toggleTtsPlay();
            }
        }
    });

    imgBtnFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (model != null) {
                isFavourite = !isFavourite;
                if (isFavourite) {
                    String imgUrl = null;
                    if (model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().size() >= 1) {
                        imgUrl = model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().get(0).getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFullSize().getSourceUrl();
                    }
                    favouriteDbController.insertData(
                            model.getID().intValue(),
                            imgUrl,
                            model.getTitle().getRendered(),
                            model.getOldDate(),
                            model.getEmbedded().getWpTerms().get(0).get(0).getName()
                    );
                } else {
                    favouriteDbController.deleteFav(clickedPostId);
                }
                setFavImage();
            }
        }
    });

    imgBtnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (model != null) {
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, model.getPageUrl());
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
            }
        }
    });

    commentsAdapter.setItemClickListener(new ListItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View view) {
            int id = view.getId();
            CommentsAndReplies clickedComment = zeroParentComments.get(position);
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.list_item:
                    ActivityUtils.getInstance().invokeCommentDetails(mActivity, CommentDetailsActivity.class, (ArrayList) commentList, clickedPostId, clickedComment, false, false);
                    break;
                case R.id.reply_text:
                    ActivityUtils.getInstance().invokeCommentDetails(mActivity, CommentDetailsActivity.class, (ArrayList) commentList, clickedPostId, clickedComment, true, false);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    tvCommnentList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActivityUtils.getInstance().invokeCommentList(mActivity,
                    CommentListActivity.class,
                    (ArrayList) commentList,
                    (ArrayList) zeroParentComments,
                    clickedPostId,
                    false);
        }
    });

    fabWriteAComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            WriteACommentFragment dialog = WriteACommentFragment.newInstance(clickedPostId, AppConstant.THIS_IS_COMMENT);
            dialog.show(manager, AppConstant.BUNDLE_KEY_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
        }
    });
}

public void loadPostDetails() {
    ApiUtils.getApiInterface().getPostDetails(clickedPostId).enqueue(new Callback<PostDetails>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PostDetails> call, Response<PostDetails> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                // bind data
                model = response.body();
                PostDetails m = model;

                // visible parent view
                lytPostDetailsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // visible comments button
                fabWriteAComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                loadCommentsAndReplies(model.getLinks().getRepliesList().get(0).getHref());

                setFavImage();


                tvPostTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(model.getTitle().getRendered()));

                String imgUrl = null;
                if (model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().size() > 0) {
                    if (model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().get(0).getMediaDetails() != null) {
                        if (model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().get(0).getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFullSize().getSourceUrl() != null) {
                            imgUrl = model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().get(0).getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFullSize().getSourceUrl();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (imgUrl != null) {
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load(imgUrl)
                            .into(imgPost);
                }

                String author = null;
                if (model.getEmbedded().getAuthors().size() >= 1) {
                    author = model.getEmbedded().getAuthors().get(0).getName();
                }

                if (author == null) {
                    author = getString(R.string.admin);
                }
                tvPostAuthor.setText(Html.fromHtml(author));

                String oldDate = model.getOldDate();
                String newDate = AppUtils.getFormattedDate(oldDate);

                if (newDate != null) {
                    tvPostDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(newDate));
                }

                String contentText = model.getContent().getRendered();

                ttsText = new StringBuilder(Html.fromHtml(model.getTitle().getRendered())).append(AppConstant.DOT).append(Html.fromHtml(model.getContent().getRendered())).toString();

                //webView.loadData(contentText, "text/html", "UTF-8");

                contentText = new StringBuilder().append(AppConstant.CSS_PROPERTIES).append(contentText).toString();
                webEngine.loadHtml(contentText);

            } else {
                showEmptyView();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PostDetails> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            // hide common loader
            hideLoader();
            // show empty view
            showEmptyView();
        }
    });
}

public void loadCommentsAndReplies(final String commentsAndRepliesLink) {

    ApiUtils.getApiInterface().getCommentsAndReplies(commentsAndRepliesLink, mPerPage).enqueue(new Callback<List<CommentsAndReplies>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<CommentsAndReplies>> call, Response<List<CommentsAndReplies>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                int totalItems = Integer.parseInt(response.headers().get(HttpParams.HEADER_TOTAL_ITEM));
                int totalPages = Integer.parseInt(response.headers().get(HttpParams.HEADER_TOTAL_PAGE));


                if (totalPages > 1) {
                    mPerPage = mPerPage * totalPages;
                    loadCommentsAndReplies(commentsAndRepliesLink);

                } else {
                    if (!commentList.isEmpty() || !zeroParentComments.isEmpty() || !onlyThreeComments.isEmpty()) {
                        commentList.clear();
                        zeroParentComments.clear();
                        onlyThreeComments.clear();
                    }

                    commentList.addAll(response.body());

                    lytCommentDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    if (commentList.size() > 0) {
                        for (CommentsAndReplies commentsAndReplies : commentList) {
                            if (commentsAndReplies.getParent().intValue() == 0) {
                                zeroParentComments.add(commentsAndReplies);
                            }
                        }

                        if (zeroParentComments.size() >= 3) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                                onlyThreeComments.add(zeroParentComments.get(i));
                            }
                        } else {
                            for (CommentsAndReplies commentsAndReplies : zeroParentComments) {
                                onlyThreeComments.add(commentsAndReplies);
                            }
                        }
                        commentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        tvCommnentList.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.all_comment), commentList.size()));
                        tvCommnentList.setClickable(true);

                    } else {
                        tvCommnentList.setClickable(false);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<CommentsAndReplies>> call, Throwable t) {
            showEmptyView();
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

private void toggleTtsPlay() {
    if (isTtsPlaying) {
        ttsEngine.releaseEngine();
        isTtsPlaying = false;
    } else {
        ttsEngine.startEngine(ttsText);
        isTtsPlaying = true;
    }
    toggleTtsView();
}

private void toggleTtsView() {
    if (isTtsPlaying) {
        imgBtnSpeaker.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_speaker_stop));
    } else {
        imgBtnSpeaker.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_speaker));
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            goToHome();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    goToHome();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ttsEngine.releaseEngine();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ttsEngine.releaseEngine();
    model = null;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isTtsPlaying) {
        isTtsPlaying = false;
        imgBtnSpeaker.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_speaker));
    }
}

@Override
public void onComplete(Boolean isCommentSuccessful, CommentsAndReplies commentsAndReplies) {
    if (isCommentSuccessful) {
        loadCommentsAndReplies(model.getLinks().getRepliesList().get(0).getHref());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == AppConstant.REQUEST_CODE_COMMENT) {
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        }
        boolean isCommentSuccessful = CommentListActivity.wasCommentSuccessful(data);
        if (isCommentSuccessful) {
            loadCommentsAndReplies(model.getLinks().getRepliesList().get(0).getHref());
        }
    }
}


private void goToHome(){
    if(fromPush || fromAppLink) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PostDetailsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

I have another file WebEngine.java, if it is this file that needs to be work done with, I'll share the code here, if necessary.

Awaiting your kind response. Thanks!